# How do I switch off the water flow of the central heating?

Tags: plumbing, central-heating, radiator

I have a pressurised central heating system. I am changing the radiator valve by freezing a section of the pipe. I was wondering if I have to switch off the flow of water of the central heating. If yes, which is device in the picture I switch off and how? Or is switching off the heating switch sufficient?

[image: Pipe work near the tank]

[image: pipe work below the boiler]

Comment: Maybe I'm just to inexperienced, but I've never heard of this approach.  Usually freezing water in a pipe is a VERY BAD THING.  How do you plan on freezing it? Dry ice?    And the other water in the pipe will need a "place to go" lest you rupture it.   Not knowing more, I'd say shut off all supplies, turn off the boiler, open at least one drain valve.   BTW:  Why not just drain the system?

Comment: I have heard of the "freeze the pipe to replace a valve" idea before, but normally in the context of "no other way to shut off water to the house". If you have a functioning building shutoff, use it. If you don't, that is the first step before working on the boiler.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the heating water from circulating in the closed loop, the circulation pump could be disconnected/switched off.

But it is better to just de-energize the central heating system which normally supplies the pump.

Switching to stand-by or just switching "off" the heating system at the control panel may not be helpful, since many controls are automatically in the anti-frost mode if switched "off".

In other words, switching off means switching to stand-by (anti-frost) in many heating controls.

In that anti-frost mode, the circulation pump is usually permanently running to protect the system, if the outdoor temperature is below a certain temperature.

The freezing method for changing valves is a standard method here in Europe, which saves time, water and money.

Nothing happens, if a short stretch of the pipe is blocked that way.

A small part of a  pipe will not  burst if frozen,  if the non-frozen water can take the overpressure.

A heating system is normally made to handle that overpressure which is unavoidable if the water is being heated up.
F.e., many installations have an expansion vessel to compensate the changing pressure. And a safety valve is mandatory.

Cave:

If something unforeseen happens, it is always helpful to be prepared to empty the system very quickly. Where is the emptying valve, is a hose connected to a drain etc.

F.e., if the icing machine stops working, electricity brown/black outs occur etc.
Or when using dry ice: running out if dry ice if the valve thread gets damaged and needs much more time for repair/exchange etc.